# Am I using std::map's find function correctly? Want to access class data

Tags: c++, stl, c++98

So the following code compiles but i'm not sure if it's doing what I want it to do...
(VS2010 for reference)

```
// Declarations

typedef std::map<unsigned int, QGF6::GameObject*> localMap;
localMap lMap;

// Code in a function that I might be using with the wrong logic:

lMap.find(p.id)->second->getPhysics()->setLinearVelocity(linVel);
```

Intended Logic:

Find the `unsigned int` value in the `map` that equals `p.id`(another unsigned int) then to that member of the `map`, access it's second data type(`GameObject*`) and do stuff.

---

So the question is whether or not that should be working 'as intended' ? It compiles but as I'm having bugs with velocity I'm thinking it might be a misunderstanding of the std::map class.

Comment: UB if element (`p.id`) is not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will work only if the searched item is actually present in the `map`. Otherwise using it will cause **undefined behavior**. You should use something like the following

```
 std::map<unsigned int, QGF6::GameObject*>::iterator itr = lMap.find(p.id);
 if(itr!= lMap.end()){ //found
  //use it
 }
```

or,

```
 QGF6::GameObject* obj = lMap[p.id];
 if( obj!=nulptr){
  //use it
 }
```

Comment: Note: it will not return `null`, but `lMap.end()`. Both are undefined behavior, but the latter tend not to crash as deterministically.

Comment: `lMap[p.id]` would return `NULL` though.

Comment: @crashmstr, actually I am using Qt map for long time in this way as showed, that's why the mistake.

Comment: Awesome that makes sense :) As it's a client that downloads the map data from a server it *should* always be right but that will help a lot with unexpected behavior checking.

Comment: Note that `lMap[p.id]` modify `lMap` (by inserting default element) when element is not found contrary to `map::find`.

Comment: Thanks for that Rakibul, did not know where to tick the accept answer so appreciate the link.